# how to restrict number field to enter only numbers in oracle apex

Tags: javascript, html, css, oracle-apex-5

I'm new to oracle apex. Currently I'm working on oracle apex 5.0. I've created an item of type number field. I want this field for entering mobile number. So, I used format masking like '9999999999'.
Now problem is, after executing that application I can able to enter alphabets also. For now, I made a validation on it, but I want my item to accept only number as input. User can't be able to add any alphabets in it.
I've also tried, putting `input type="tel" maxlength="10"` and `input type="number" max="10"` this code in my `HTML Form Element Attributes` field as well as `HTML Form Element CSS Classes` field but it doesn't work.

No matter which query I put in `HTML Form Element Attributes` it will result in problem which is shown in image [**Problem with HTML Form Element Attributes**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KRSJ.png).Now, as you can see in that image, this time I've added  `<input type="tel" maxlength=10 pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}">` this statement, but having that same problem.
Now I also tried to put that statement into `HTML Form Element CSS Classes`, and here that problem is not appearing but still I'm able to add alphabets in it.

Please guide me how to do that.

Comment: In html you can do this `<input type="tel" maxlength=10 pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}">`.

Comment: @HastaTamang it's not working let me update my question so i can show an image what happened.

Comment: Yes that is expected behavior, but your form will not submit if it fails validation. BTW you can also add required to input.

Comment: Have you tried posting your form with alphabets in that tel input?

Comment: @HastaTamang As I already said I've made a validation & it works, but I don't want my seniors to finger me out, to that alphabetical input problem. & yes I tried posting alphabets in tel input, see that image. & can explain in brief about that 'add required to input' part.

Comment: Required just means that the input field cannot be left empty on submit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JavaScript to listen `onkeydown` event and check the keycode.

If the keycode is a letter prevent it from being inserted into the input element. To see the list of keycodes check [here](https://keycode.info/)

```js
function validateNumber(event) {
  var keyCode = event.keyCode;
  var excludedKeys = [8, 37, 39, 46];

  if (!((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) ||
      (keyCode >= 96 && keyCode <= 105) ||
      (excludedKeys.includes(keyCode)))) {
    console.log("alphabets are not allowed");
    event.preventDefault();

  }

  console.log("keycode: " + keyCode);
}
```

```html
<form>

  <div>
    <label>Mobile Number</label>
    <input type="tel" placeholder="Enter Mobile no" onkeydown="return validateNumber(event)" required>
  </div>


</form>
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vh1px9yn/)

Comment: Hi @HastaTamang, thank you, it works. but still it shows me code snippet(some of the part of code) above the number field. Please see the image again which is shared already. In that, after the editable field that code has been shown like that I'm seeing right now, what should I do for that?.

Comment: Hi @HastaTamang instead of that html code I've just added `type="tel" maxlength="10" placeholder="Enter Mobile no" onkeydown="return validateNumber(event)" required` on my `HTML Form Element Attributes`. And it works but only on chrome browser that code snippet is also gone. But it didn't work on Firefox and internet browser. Can you please guide me for that.

Comment: Ok, I got it it's because of my browser was not updated. Anyways thank you @HastaTamang. You really help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option would be to create a **validation** whose type is **Item is numeric**. You don't need any additional coding to do that.

Also, if table column's datatype is `NUMBER`, you won't be able to insert anything but numbers in there, Oracle won't let you.

Comment: I am using `number field`. I also applied a validation and my column is also of number data type in table. But what is my question is how to restrict that field, so nobody can able to type any alphabets. So, user will not be able to add any characters in it.

Comment: Do you mean that you'd want to prevent entering, for example, `a` into that item? No matter how hard I try and push the `a` key on the keyboard, nothing would happen? Sorry, that's beyond my knowledge. I'm quite satisfied with what Apex currently offers.

Answer (score 0):

Prevent typing non-alphabetic characters in specific input id's for pages that have more than one input item. It's useful for Oracle Apex developers.

Append it like this in the HTML header of page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateNumber(event) {
  const activeElmnt = document.activeElement;  
  var keyCode = event.keyCode;
  var excludedKeys = [8, 37, 39, 46];
 
   if ( activeElmnt.id == "input id in HTML page"){
        if (!((keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) ||
            (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122) ||
            (excludedKeys.includes(keyCode)))) {
            console.log("alphabets are not allowed");
            event.preventDefault();

  }
}
  console.log("keycode: " + keyCode + "ActiveElemet: "+activeElmnt.id);
}
</script>
```

Append it like this in the HTML body of a page:

```
onkeydown="validateNumber(event);"
```